# What's with the `of` and `&` in the Coq Inductive definition?

Tags: coq

I just saw someone defined an Inductive type in Coq in an unfamiliar syntax, like this:

```
Inductive nat_tree : Type :=
| NatLeaf
| NatNode of color & nat_tree & nat & nat_tree.
```

The syntax I am used to look like [this](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html#hevea_command11):

```
Inductive ident : sort :=
    ident1  :   type1
|   …        
|   identn  :   typen
```

Can anyone explain what's the new syntax?

BTW, this is from a ssrflect tutorial. And I wonder if it's a ssr addition.

Comment: My guess is that it's used because it mimics quite well the syntax of OCaml's variant types. Never seen it before thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right: this syntax is defined by Ssreflect. Both are defined as syntactic sugar for declaring an anonymous argument: `of T` and `& T` mean `(_ : T)`; that is, an unnamed argument of type `T`. Thus, the definition of `nat_tree` is equivalent to the one below.

```
Inductive nat_tree :=
| NatLeaf
| NatNode (_ : color) (_ : nat_tree) (_ : nat) (_ : nat_tree).
```

You could also have given names to each argument:

```
Inductive nat_tree :=
| NatLeaf
| NatNode (c : color) (t1 : nat_tree) (n : nat) (t2 : nat_tree).
```

As gallais pointed out, this makes the syntax of data-type declarations in Coq more similar to OCaml's. Note that the declaration above does not give the return type of each constructor. In standard Coq, specifying the return type is optional when all the arguments are given using this syntax, and when the type being defined is *uniform*. This means that we are allowed to define the `list` type as

```
Inductive list (T : Type) :=
| nil
| cons (t : T) (l : list T).
```

but are required to define the type of length-indexed lists as follows (because of the `nat` index):

```
Inductive vector (T : Type) : nat -> Type :=
| vnil : vector T O
| vcons (n : nat) (t : T) (v : vector T n) : vector T (S n).
```

Comment: Is it documented somehow, somewhere? I've hit it trying to follow PnP, where notation just thrown at you with 0 explanation in one place and then used for an exercise. Searching through docs linked there gave nothing.